# Supporting Container Images in Mesos Containerizer does not work

Tags: mesos

In order to startup a container using docker image, I write a taskinfo like this:

```
ci = taskinfo.container
ci.type = mesos_pb2.ContainerInfo.MESOS

mesos = ci.mesos
image = mesos.image
image.type = mesos_pb2.Image.DOCKER

dc = image.docker
dc.name = 'library/redis'
```

In fact, the container is running, but without the image of `library/redis`, something else.

the log of mesos-slave said that:

> Oct 10 19:48:52 node35.com mesos-slave[63108]: I1010 19:48:52.910619 63127 docker.cpp:1020] Skipping non-docker container

what is the problem, any example?

mesos-slave log:

```
Oct 13 10:52:26 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:52:26.696311 28226 slave.cpp:1495] Got assigned task 12f6df8a-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d for framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078
Oct 13 10:52:26 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:52:26.700240 28226 slave.cpp:1495] Got assigned task 12f6e246-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d for framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078
Oct 13 10:52:26 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:52:26.701413 28226 slave.cpp:1614] Launching task 12f6df8a-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d for framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078
Oct 13 10:52:26 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:52:26.708668 28226 paths.cpp:528] Trying to chown '/export/mfs/mesos/node35/slaves/98914c7b-dee2-44a9-aa9b-16e5bfe72dbc-S0/frameworks/f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078/executors/12f6df8a-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d/runs/3e168059-a83b-41c9-8fb1-856b8ff15fa1' to user 'root'
Oct 13 10:52:26 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:52:26.716497 28226 slave.cpp:5674] Launching executor 12f6df8a-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d of framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078 with resources cpus(*):0.1; mem(*):32 in work directory '/export/mfs/mesos/node35/slaves/98914c7b-dee2-44a9-aa9b-16e5bfe72dbc-S0/frameworks/f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078/executors/12f6df8a-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d/runs/3e168059-a83b-41c9-8fb1-856b8ff15fa1'
Oct 13 10:52:26 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:52:26.716868 28226 slave.cpp:1840] Queuing task '12f6df8a-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d' for executor '12f6df8a-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d' of framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078
Oct 13 10:52:26 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:52:26.717013 28226 slave.cpp:1614] Launching task 12f6e246-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d for framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078
Oct 13 10:52:26 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:52:26.717124 28207 docker.cpp:1020] Skipping non-docker container
Oct 13 10:52:26 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:52:26.717418 28212 containerizer.cpp:781] Starting container '3e168059-a83b-41c9-8fb1-856b8ff15fa1' for executor '12f6df8a-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d' of framework 'f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078'
Oct 13 10:52:26 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:52:26.719498 28226 paths.cpp:528] Trying to chown '/export/mfs/mesos/node35/slaves/98914c7b-dee2-44a9-aa9b-16e5bfe72dbc-S0/frameworks/f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078/executors/12f6e246-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d/runs/8e35f996-2e1a-4e9e-9ffd-6fc28736eb0b' to user 'root'
Oct 13 10:52:26 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:52:26.722229 28199 provisioner.cpp:294] Provisioning image rootfs '/export/mfs/mesos/node35/provisioner/containers/3e168059-a83b-41c9-8fb1-856b8ff15fa1/backends/copy/rootfses/17f3b84c-497f-4ed2-ae1e-20dec8e0365f' for container 3e168059-a83b-41c9-8fb1-856b8ff15fa1
Oct 13 10:52:26 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:52:26.726907 28226 slave.cpp:5674] Launching executor 12f6e246-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d of framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078 with resources cpus(*):0.1; mem(*):32 in work directory '/export/mfs/mesos/node35/slaves/98914c7b-dee2-44a9-aa9b-16e5bfe72dbc-S0/frameworks/f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078/executors/12f6e246-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d/runs/8e35f996-2e1a-4e9e-9ffd-6fc28736eb0b'
Oct 13 10:52:26 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:52:26.727380 28226 slave.cpp:1840] Queuing task '12f6e246-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d' for executor '12f6e246-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d' of framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078
Oct 13 10:52:26 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:52:26.727604 28219 docker.cpp:1020] Skipping non-docker container
Oct 13 10:52:26 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:52:26.727931 28207 containerizer.cpp:781] Starting container '8e35f996-2e1a-4e9e-9ffd-6fc28736eb0b' for executor '12f6e246-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d' of framework 'f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078'
Oct 13 10:52:26 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:52:26.730805 28206 provisioner.cpp:294] Provisioning image rootfs '/export/mfs/mesos/node35/provisioner/containers/8e35f996-2e1a-4e9e-9ffd-6fc28736eb0b/backends/copy/rootfses/9db760a0-3416-4fcb-8a20-6c49876db408' for container 8e35f996-2e1a-4e9e-9ffd-6fc28736eb0b
Oct 13 10:53:26 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:53:26.112534 28200 slave.cpp:4591] Current disk usage 84.30%. Max allowed age: 9.580097596579167hrs
Oct 13 10:54:26 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:26.113219 28199 slave.cpp:4591] Current disk usage 84.32%. Max allowed age: 9.549836767814444hrs
Oct 13 10:54:49 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:49.075541 28208 linux_launcher.cpp:281] Cloning child process with flags = CLONE_NEWNS
Oct 13 10:54:49 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:49.083299 28208 systemd.cpp:96] Assigned child process '28626' to 'mesos_executors.slice'
Oct 13 10:54:49 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:49.584405 28215 slave.cpp:2828] Got registration for executor '12f6e246-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d' of framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078 from executor(1)@192.168.184.35:52485
Oct 13 10:54:49 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:49.586071 28220 slave.cpp:2005] Sending queued task '12f6e246-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d' to executor '12f6e246-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d' of framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078 at executor(1)@192.168.184.35:52485
Oct 13 10:54:49 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:49.601891 28210 slave.cpp:3211] Handling status update TASK_RUNNING (UUID: 2216c9b4-6355-477d-9b26-536f91287f8f) for task 12f6e246-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d of framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078 from executor(1)@192.168.184.35:52485
Oct 13 10:54:49 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:49.602941 28203 status_update_manager.cpp:320] Received status update TASK_RUNNING (UUID: 2216c9b4-6355-477d-9b26-536f91287f8f) for task 12f6e246-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d of framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078
Oct 13 10:54:49 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:49.603276 28214 slave.cpp:3604] Forwarding the update TASK_RUNNING (UUID: 2216c9b4-6355-477d-9b26-536f91287f8f) for task 12f6e246-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d of framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078 to master@192.168.184.35:5050
Oct 13 10:54:49 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:49.603421 28214 slave.cpp:3514] Sending acknowledgement for status update TASK_RUNNING (UUID: 2216c9b4-6355-477d-9b26-536f91287f8f) for task 12f6e246-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d of framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078 to executor(1)@192.168.184.35:52485
Oct 13 10:54:49 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:49.606329 28200 status_update_manager.cpp:392] Received status update acknowledgement (UUID: 2216c9b4-6355-477d-9b26-536f91287f8f) for task 12f6e246-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d of framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078
Oct 13 10:54:49 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:49.903795 28208 slave.cpp:3211] Handling status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: e8bf5921-bd27-467a-98a5-8dca726953bf) for task 12f6e246-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d of framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078 from executor(1)@192.168.184.35:52485
Oct 13 10:54:49 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:49.905704 28226 status_update_manager.cpp:320] Received status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: e8bf5921-bd27-467a-98a5-8dca726953bf) for task 12f6e246-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d of framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078
Oct 13 10:54:49 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:49.905941 28206 slave.cpp:3604] Forwarding the update TASK_FAILED (UUID: e8bf5921-bd27-467a-98a5-8dca726953bf) for task 12f6e246-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d of framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078 to master@192.168.184.35:5050
Oct 13 10:54:49 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:49.906096 28206 slave.cpp:3514] Sending acknowledgement for status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: e8bf5921-bd27-467a-98a5-8dca726953bf) for task 12f6e246-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d of framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078 to executor(1)@192.168.184.35:52485
Oct 13 10:54:49 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:49.908535 28202 slave.cpp:2218] Asked to shut down framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078 by master@192.168.184.35:5050
Oct 13 10:54:49 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:49.908571 28202 slave.cpp:2243] Shutting down framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078
Oct 13 10:54:49 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:49.908589 28202 slave.cpp:4407] Shutting down executor '12f6df8a-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d' of framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078
Oct 13 10:54:49 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: W1013 10:54:49.908603 28202 slave.hpp:768] Unable to send event to executor '12f6df8a-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d' of framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078: unknown connection type
Oct 13 10:54:49 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:49.908638 28202 slave.cpp:4407] Shutting down executor '12f6e246-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d' of framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078 at executor(1)@192.168.184.35:52485
Oct 13 10:54:50 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:50.082800 28202 linux_launcher.cpp:281] Cloning child process with flags = CLONE_NEWNS
Oct 13 10:54:50 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:50.089779 28202 systemd.cpp:96] Assigned child process '28699' to 'mesos_executors.slice'
Oct 13 10:54:50 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: W1013 10:54:50.169484 28225 slave.cpp:4026] Killing executor '12f6df8a-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d' of framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078 because the framework is terminating
Oct 13 10:54:50 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:50.169997 28210 containerizer.cpp:1622] Destroying container '3e168059-a83b-41c9-8fb1-856b8ff15fa1'
Oct 13 10:54:50 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:50.173152 28215 cgroups.cpp:2670] Freezing cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/mesos/3e168059-a83b-41c9-8fb1-856b8ff15fa1
Oct 13 10:54:50 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:50.277705 28219 cgroups.cpp:1409] Successfully froze cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/mesos/3e168059-a83b-41c9-8fb1-856b8ff15fa1 after 104480us
Oct 13 10:54:50 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:50.280438 28219 cgroups.cpp:2688] Thawing cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/mesos/3e168059-a83b-41c9-8fb1-856b8ff15fa1
Oct 13 10:54:50 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:50.283026 28219 cgroups.cpp:1438] Successfully thawed cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/mesos/3e168059-a83b-41c9-8fb1-856b8ff15fa1 after 2.539008ms
Oct 13 10:54:50 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:50.369166 28220 containerizer.cpp:1863] Executor for container '3e168059-a83b-41c9-8fb1-856b8ff15fa1' has exited
Oct 13 10:54:50 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:50.376343 28230 provisioner.cpp:434] Destroying container rootfs at '/export/mfs/mesos/node35/provisioner/containers/3e168059-a83b-41c9-8fb1-856b8ff15fa1/backends/copy/rootfses/17f3b84c-497f-4ed2-ae1e-20dec8e0365f' for container 3e168059-a83b-41c9-8fb1-856b8ff15fa1
Oct 13 10:54:50 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:50.923599 28214 slave.cpp:3732] executor(1)@192.168.184.35:52485 exited
Oct 13 10:54:50 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:50.970942 28218 containerizer.cpp:1863] Executor for container '8e35f996-2e1a-4e9e-9ffd-6fc28736eb0b' has exited
Oct 13 10:54:50 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:50.970993 28218 containerizer.cpp:1622] Destroying container '8e35f996-2e1a-4e9e-9ffd-6fc28736eb0b'
Oct 13 10:54:50 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:50.974090 28226 cgroups.cpp:2670] Freezing cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/mesos/8e35f996-2e1a-4e9e-9ffd-6fc28736eb0b
Oct 13 10:54:50 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:50.976815 28210 cgroups.cpp:1409] Successfully froze cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/mesos/8e35f996-2e1a-4e9e-9ffd-6fc28736eb0b after 2.661888ms
Oct 13 10:54:50 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:50.979657 28229 cgroups.cpp:2688] Thawing cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/mesos/8e35f996-2e1a-4e9e-9ffd-6fc28736eb0b
Oct 13 10:54:50 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:50.982293 28229 cgroups.cpp:1438] Successfully thawed cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/mesos/8e35f996-2e1a-4e9e-9ffd-6fc28736eb0b after 2.580224ms
Oct 13 10:54:50 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:50.989307 28212 provisioner.cpp:434] Destroying container rootfs at '/export/mfs/mesos/node35/provisioner/containers/8e35f996-2e1a-4e9e-9ffd-6fc28736eb0b/backends/copy/rootfses/9db760a0-3416-4fcb-8a20-6c49876db408' for container 8e35f996-2e1a-4e9e-9ffd-6fc28736eb0b
Oct 13 10:54:53 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:53.781436 28219 slave.cpp:4089] Executor '12f6df8a-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d' of framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078 terminated with signal Killed
Oct 13 10:54:53 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:53.781533 28219 slave.cpp:4193] Cleaning up executor '12f6df8a-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d' of framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078
Oct 13 10:54:53 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:53.783816 28218 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/export/mfs/mesos/node35/slaves/98914c7b-dee2-44a9-aa9b-16e5bfe72dbc-S0/frameworks/f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078/executors/12f6df8a-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d/runs/3e168059-a83b-41c9-8fb1-856b8ff15fa1' for gc 6.9999909290163days in the future
Oct 13 10:54:53 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:53.784271 28228 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/export/mfs/mesos/node35/slaves/98914c7b-dee2-44a9-aa9b-16e5bfe72dbc-S0/frameworks/f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078/executors/12f6df8a-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d' for gc 6.99999092334519days in the future
Oct 13 10:54:54 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:54.284092 28214 slave.cpp:4089] Executor '12f6e246-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d' of framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078 exited with status 0
Oct 13 10:54:54 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:54.284144 28214 slave.cpp:4193] Cleaning up executor '12f6e246-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d' of framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078 at executor(1)@192.168.184.35:52485
Oct 13 10:54:54 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:54.285564 28223 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/export/mfs/mesos/node35/slaves/98914c7b-dee2-44a9-aa9b-16e5bfe72dbc-S0/frameworks/f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078/executors/12f6e246-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d/runs/8e35f996-2e1a-4e9e-9ffd-6fc28736eb0b' for gc 6.99999669571852days in the future
Oct 13 10:54:54 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:54.285995 28214 slave.cpp:4281] Cleaning up framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078
Oct 13 10:54:54 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:54.286053 28207 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/export/mfs/mesos/node35/slaves/98914c7b-dee2-44a9-aa9b-16e5bfe72dbc-S0/frameworks/f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078/executors/12f6e246-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d' for gc 6.99999669025481days in the future
Oct 13 10:54:54 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:54.286100 28206 status_update_manager.cpp:282] Closing status update streams for framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078
Oct 13 10:54:54 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:54.286559 28227 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/export/mfs/mesos/node35/slaves/98914c7b-dee2-44a9-aa9b-16e5bfe72dbc-S0/frameworks/f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078' for gc 6.99999668392296days in the future
Oct 13 10:54:54 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:54.909030 28214 slave.cpp:4448] Framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078 seems to have exited. Ignoring shutdown timeout for executor '12f6df8a-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d'
Oct 13 10:54:54 node35.com mesos-slave[28198]: I1013 10:54:54.909081 28214 slave.cpp:4448] Framework f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078 seems to have exited. Ignoring shutdown timeout for executor '12f6e246-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d'
```

scheudlar log:

```
I1013 10:52:26.667783 119228 sched.cpp:743] Framework registered with f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078
I1013 10:52:26.000668 119196 scheduler.py:209] Tensorflow cluster registered. ( http://192.168.184.35:5050/#/frameworks/f1f0d8b9-2958-4fd6-9f06-81ce428255ae-0078 )
I1013 10:52:26.000669 119196 scheduler.py:169] Offered cpus: 32.0 offered mem: 63133.0 offered gpus: 4 offerd port: 31000~32000 on 192.168.184.35
I1013 10:52:26.000670 119196 scheduler.py:193] Registering in zookeeper /12f6d7d8-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d/member/_job_ps_task_0, value: 192.168.184.35:31000
I1013 10:52:26.000688 119196 scheduler.py:200] Allocating resource for /job:ps/task:0 successful
I1013 10:52:26.000689 119196 scheduler.py:193] Registering in zookeeper /12f6d7d8-90f0-11e6-859e-44a842176f5d/member/_job_worker_task_0, value: 192.168.184.35:31001
I1013 10:52:26.000697 119196 scheduler.py:200] Allocating resource for /job:worker/task:0 successful
I1013 10:54:49.000609 119196 scheduler.py:218] Task /job:worker/task:0: TASK_RUNNING
W1013 10:54:49.000911 119196 scheduler.py:225] Task /job:worker/task:0: Command exited with status 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably Mesos agent decided to use docker containerizer instead of mesos containerizer. Check that agent specifies `--containerizers=mesos,docker` and not `--containerizers=docker,mesos`. More on containerizers and importance of the order [here](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/containerizer/).

Comment: I think it's not the problem, no matter `--containerizers=mesos,docker` or `--containerizers=docker,mesos`. I am wondering whether mesos pull image from a registry, because I can't find any image called `library/redis` on my machine

Comment: The log line you provided definitely hints docker containerizer is invoked. This conflicts with the type of image you provide. Could you please grep agent logs for the task id and share the result?

Comment: @ rukletsov, I have updated log, something is wrong?

Comment: @wang: the task is failing for some reason. Can you also share the executor's log? Also I see the framework shuts down, do you trigger this?

Comment: thanks for your help, the program run ok now, it can find the right image, but I haven't know the reason, I'll try

Comment: Hm, strange. Please do come back if you have a pointer or an explanation!

Comment: I set `docker_store_dir` to `/tmp/mesos/docker`, in this dir, I cat the file `storedImages`,  it's not the same with the previous, the previous has more than one image in it, so mesos startup the first image in `storedImages` file?